# Will linking a category menu to the product manufacturer hurt search engine rankings?

Tags: seo, redirects, ranking

Our company is the **official** and **only distributor** of a well known manufacturer in our region.

We are building a new website, where we want to add the products we sell. So far we have multiple categories.

My question is: if we link the product categories to the manufacturer's website, how will that affect our ranking?

Basically, when a user clicks on our "home products" category, it should go to the "home products" of our manufacturer.

Comment: Why not duplicate the content and use the canonical tag?

Comment: There is a lot of content, but the issue is wont that affect the ranking ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the mozrank (or whichever authority measure you like) of both websites and the individual pages. If the manufacturers page is stronger than yours, and you are linking to them, then you risk helping them out rank you.

On the other hand will NOT linking to them hurt your sales/conversion rate?

Are you using 'boiler plate' copy across a large percentage of your websites pages? It sounds you might be, which i'd consider a higher priority to find a way around.

In reality however I don't think the links will matter all that much in the grand scheme, particularly if users are likely to use Geogrpahic terms in there search phrases too.

Worst case scenario, you launch without them, rank track some phrases, then add the links in. Observe the difference, act accordingly.

Comment: I made an error while providing the information. We do have a online shop that is different from the website we are currently working on. What we want is that out clients know the products we offer , not buy them online ( from the new website). And yes , the clients will use geographic terms or at least thats our target.